# Trying to change the value of an item in a table using onclick event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I need to add clickhandler event to each item in the table in such a way that,when I click on any item in the table,the quantity item should generate random number between 0 to 20.This is the code I have tried so far.Product has {name,price,quantity}.

```
import React from 'react';
  function ProductRow({ product }) {

  function handleClick(){
    var min=0;
    var max=20;
    product.quantity=min + (Math.random() * (max-min));
  }
  
const getColor = (quantity) => {
  
  if (quantity === 0) return 'red';

  if (quantity < 10) return 'blue';

  return '';



};
return (
      <tr style={{ color: getColor(product.quantity) }}     onClick={handleClick} >
          <td >{product.name}</td>
          <td >{product.price}</td>
          <td >{product.quantity}</td>
      </tr>
  );
}

export default ProductRow;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the quantity into state, and in `handleClick`, you can set that state:

```
function ProductRow({ product }) {
    const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(product.quantity);
    function handleClick() {
        var min = 0;
        var max = 20;
        setQuantity(min + (Math.random() * (max - min)));
    }

    const getColor = (quantity) => {
        if (quantity === 0) return 'red';
        if (quantity < 10) return 'blue';
        return '';
    };
    return (
        <tr style={{ color: getColor(quantity) }} onClick={handleClick} >
            <td >{product.name}</td>
            <td >{product.price}</td>
            <td >{quantity}</td>
        </tr>
    );
}
```

Comment: the values are not changing with click.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the standalone `quantity` variable, as in the code in the answer? Using `product.quantity` won't work, because it's not in state

Comment: but if I change it to quantity,the conditional statement is not working for 0 to change the color to red after clicking.

Comment: Like the code in the answer shows, call `getColor(quantity)`, not `getColor(product.quantity)` - you need to always use the variable that's in state, not the prop

Answer (score 0):

you should maintain a local state variable for the value of that cell `qty`

set the initial value using the useEffect hook for the first time

```
useEffect = ( () => {
      setQty(product.quantity)
   } ,[])
```

then in the onClick handler do the same

and show the result in your table cell .

here is the complete code

```
import React from 'react';
  function ProductRow({ product }) {

  const [qty , setQty] = useState(0);

   useEffect = ( () => {
      setQty(product.quantity)
   } ,[])

  function handleClick(){
    var min=0;
    var max=20;
    setQty(min + (Math.random() * (max-min)));
  }
  
const getColor = (quantity) => {
  
  if (quantity === 0) return 'red';

  if (quantity < 10) return 'blue';

  return '';



};
return (
      <tr style={{ color: getColor(product.quantity) }}     onClick={handleClick} >
          <td >{product.name}</td>
          <td >{product.price}</td>
          <td >{qty}</td>
      </tr>
  );
}

export default ProductRow;
```